# How to create a new configuration using External tools in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, multi-tenant, xcopy, visual-studio-macros, external-tools

I am creating a multi tenant client mobile(Cordova) application. I want to copy the  appropriate client files from a folder to the project in deployment time.

I am using WebStorm IDE for development. Project has a folder called branding which contains multiple client specific files in folders. Using WebStorm, I created a new configuration using external tools.

To copy the files in deployment time, I used the command `xcopy $FileParentDir$branding\abc\*.* $FileParentDir$www\branding /S /Y`

It says `cannot run program... CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use '`Parameters`' field to specify xcopy options - leave '`xcopy`' as '`Program`' and move '`$FileParentDir$\branding\abc\*.* $FileParentDir$\www\branding /S /Y`' to '`Parameters`' field

Comment: OMG !!!! You are the Man. I never taught I can end up with such ease. You made my day.